# React router NavLink not changing to new component

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to reroute to a new page in my react app using react router. Currently when I click on the Projects NavLink it is changing the url from `localhost:3000` to `localhost:3000/projects` however the page is not changing. I have to press enter on the search bar to get to the new page after clicking on the link.

my app.js looks like this

```
class App extends Component {
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <NavBar />
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/projects" component={Projects} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and the link in my NavBar.js looks like this..

```
import { NavLink, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'//what I am importing
import { Link } from 'react-scroll'; 

 <BrowserRouter>
   <NavLink to="/projects">Projects</NavLink>
 </BrowserRouter>
```

Any reason why it wont work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need to wrap your navbar.js in browser router.  Instead move your navbar component within the browser router in the app.js.  Ensure that the component is within browser router but outside of the switch.  That should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

In your NavBar.js, try `<NavLink to="/projects">Projects</NavLink>` instead of just projects.

Comment: I have tried this but the page isnt making the transition. When I right click on the libk and click 'open link in new tab' it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot '/' in `<NavLink to="projects">Projects</NavLink>` before to property . try this:
`<NavLink to="/projects">Projects</NavLink>`
and just wrap your most outer component with `<BrowserRouter></BrowserRouter>` like app.js or index.js.

Comment: I have tried this but the page isnt making the transition. When I right click on the libk and click 'open link in new tab' it works.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling `<React.StrictMode>` in App.js allows for switching between components.

Comment: Maybe you can add a link to the documentation to make it easier to understand why this works.